# Apache - url not found in some cases

Tags: apache, url, url-rewriting

I've got some problem with my Zend application uploaded on Ubuntu server. While such urls: `http://www.domain.com`, `http://www.domain.com/admin/panel` work, only this type of links: `http://www.domain.com/index/51-picture.html` show: `Not found.The requested URL /index/51-picture.html was not found on this server.`

Apache.conf

```
<Directory/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Allow from All
</Direcory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

sites-available/domain.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain

        <Directory /var/www/domain/>
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I've also enabled: `a2enmod rewrite`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the solution. Just removed `MultiViews` from domain configuration file. Now everything's fine.